# Converting array with .join not saving value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method `do_stuff` that takes a string as a value. However, an array of two strings is occasionally passed in. In this situation, I need to convert the array to a single string (without commas). So for example, ["hello", "world"] should become "hello world".

So, if value = array, join the two strings, otherwise leave it alone.

The following line I have does what I want, but I am struggling with actually "saving" the value before passing it to the method `do_other_stuff`.

```
  def do_stuff(value)
    value.join("") if value.is_a? Array

    do_other_stuff(value)
  end
```

So I think i am close, but what would be the best way to ensure `value` is manipulated before passing it to `do_other_stuff` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`join` does not change your object, you're wasting its return value

```
value = value.join if value.is_a? Array
```

Note that `""` is the default for the join parameter, so I got rid of it

Comment: Works great. Chose this as the accepted compared to a few others just because of the additional advice on leaving of the empty string parameter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
value.join("") if value.is_a? Array
```

With

```rb
value = value.join("") if value.is_a? Array
```

Basically you need to reassign result back to `value`

Answer (score 0):

Use [duck typing](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/duck_typing.html) instead of checking the class:

```
def do_stuff(value)
  do_other_stuff(value.try(:join, '')  ||  value)
end
```

`.try` is from ActiveSupport and will return nil if the object does not respond to the method. In plain old ruby you would write this as:

```
def do_stuff(value)
  do_other_stuff(value.respond_to?(:join) ? value.join("") : value)
end
```